# how to get next database string in java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have stored some  multi-term strings like `[john smith, mary jones, mary john albert,..]` in database one by one.

1. how to get next, next string from database?
    [already i inserted some strings in DB, again i need to use those string from db and i retrived using stringtokenizer [st1m], then i need check each multi-term string, one by one]
2. how to check how many times "john" occurs in the database?
    [here john is occured 2 times in multi-term string]
3. what is the use of v[j].trim?

my code is:

```
stas1.executeUpdate("insert into c_ngram values('"+v[j]+"')");

            }
             StringTokenizer st1m=new StringTokenizer(v[j],"/");

              int i1=0;
              String posm1[]=new String[10000];
            while(st1m.hasMoreElements())
            {
               posm1[i1]=st1m.nextToken().replace("/", "").trim();

              il++;
              int ikm=0;
              while(st1m.next()!=null)
                         {

                          //===========;

                               ikm++;

                         }
```

here v[j] is the strings in database. 
please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to clarify your question, do you want to know the number of occurrences of a single string while inserting or in a query?

Comment: hello Diogo de Góes Zanetti, i have edited my question. pls help me

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer using the same order:

When you are trying to iterate in a string array of strings in a single string, like "One,Two,Three", you can do this in two forms.
The first form is using the method `split(",")`, this method will transform you String in a String[] then you can use a loop to iterate between the elements of your String array:

```
String x = "One,two,three";
String[] array = x.split(",");
for(String item: array){
  System.out.println(item);
}
```

You can use the StringTokenizer and use iterate between the elements.

```
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(x,",");
//then you do this iterator
while(tokens.hasMoreElements()){
  System.out.println(tokens.nextElement());
}
```

For your second question, lets consider you are inserting a name for each element.
Lets use a table for example: person(integer id,varchar name) and you are inserting your names from your string like this example below:

```
String x = "john smith, mary jones, mary john albert";
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(x,",");
//then you do this iterator
while(tokens.hasMoreElements()){
  ... insert each element.
}
```

when you want to go to database and locate for example names where contains John use a query using like.

```
Select p.name from person p where p.name like '%John%';
```

Using this query the database will try to find in every element and column name the text `John`.

The third answer the .trim() method removes spaces before the first character and after the last character.

```
String name = "   Ana Maria    ";
System.out.println(name.trim());
```

The response will be `Ana Maria`;

**Look more at**

About String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

About StringTokenizer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

About QUERY LIKE operators: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp